# Can't Send while looped input field data from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two input fields with same class name and the same data.

Here is my while loop generated input field

```
<tr>
  <td>                                   
  <input onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" class="ot_value" name="ot_value" type="text" value="10">
  <input type="hidden" name="ot_id" class="ot_id" value="1">                                  
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <input onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" class="ot_value" name="ot_value" type="text" value="11">
  <input type="hidden" name="ot_id" class="ot_id" value="2">                                  
  </td>
</tr>
```

I was trying to send data from ajax to php when user change any value.

Here is my jquery

```
function mySubmit(theForm) {
    var ot_value= $(".ot_value").val();
    var ot_id= $(".ot_id").val();
    $.ajax({
       type:"post",
         url:"../apis/update_ot.php",
         data: "ot_value=" + ot_value+ "&ot_id=" + ot_id,
            success:function(data){   
            alert(data);
       }
        
    });
}
```

I was able to send data when user is changing any input field data. But the problem is that, it's taking only the 1st row data.

How can I get the exact data, that what user are changing in input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have jQuery, use it

remove `onchange="mySubmit(this.form)"` from the field and do

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ot_value").on("change", function() {
    const ot_value = $(this).val();
    const ot_id = $(this).next(".ot_id").val();
    console.log("about to submit",ot_value,ot_id)
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "../apis/update_ot.php",
      data: "ot_value=" + ot_value + "&ot_id=" + ot_id,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="ot_value" name="ot_value" type="text" value="10">
        <input type="hidden" name="ot_id" class="ot_id" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="ot_value" name="ot_value" type="text" value="11">
        <input type="hidden" name="ot_id" class="ot_id" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: boss it's showing me that Uncaught ReferenceError: mySubmit is not defined

Comment: moreover if I remove onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" from input field it's not calling the php file.

Comment: boss I have edited my answer. I provided my html data which was the while looped generated

Comment: Boss same problem after removing onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" fr

Comment: ok sorry, and it worked for me, and you solved my another problem.